# How do you write a Java program to authenticate to an Aurora MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am having a problem writing a Java program that will run a SQL query on an Aurora database.

I know my database's name is goodnameofdb.

I run this command: aws rds describe-db-instances | grep DBInstanceIdentifier

I see this:

```
        "ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [],
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": "goodnameofdb"
        "ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [],
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": "goodnameofdb-us-west-2b"
```

I know my Aurora database's address.  I run this command: aws rds describe-db-instances | grep goodnameofdb-us-west-2b.abcdef123456

I see this:

> "Address": "goodnameofdb-us-west-2b.abcdef123456.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"

My Java program compiles.  I have the driver in the correct directory too.

I have a Java program with this as the code:

```
import java.sql.*;
class MysqlCon{
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://goodnameofdb-us-west-2b.abcdef123456.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/goodnameofdb","jdoe","securepassword");
 Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("show tables");
while(rs.next())
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));
con.close();
}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
}
}
```

When I run the compiled program, it does not work.  I see this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'goodnameofdb'

I am running my Java program from an EC-2 instance that is in the same VPC that the Aurora database is in.  (I checked via AWS CLI commands.)  I expect the program to connect to the Aurora database and authenticate.
What is wrong with my connection JDBC connection string?  Or why am I getting this error?

Update: when I remove the "goodnameofdb" after the ":3306/" part of the string and recompile the program, I get an error when I run the program.  The error that I receive is

> java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

I therefore think that a database name must be there.  My AWS CLI commands seem to tell me that I have the name correct.

Comment: Are you able to open the DB using mysql tools from your ec2 instance?  (eg.  `mysql -hgoodnameofdb-us-west-2b.abcdef123456.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -ujdoe -psecurepassword goodnameofdb`)

Comment: No.  I get "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database goodnameofdb"

Comment: Does it work with `goodnameofdb-us-west-2b`?

Comment: No.  Please note that the endpoint (as the AWS console shows) includes "abcdef123456".  I tried variations of goodnameofdb (including using the endpoint that the AWS console showed).  They all come back with "Unknown database..."

Comment: `...amazonaws.com:3306/goodnameofdb` << why is `goodnameofdb` **here?**  This is where you specify the schema name you want to use as the default database schema for this connection.  You are connecting to the server fine, then trying to use a database (schema) name that does not exist there.  Replace this with the correct value, or eliminate it.

Comment: When I remove it, I get "java.sql.SQLException: No database selected"
What would the correct value be?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the database "goodnameofdb " is not exist.
You can check from mysql commond line.

`mysql -hgoodnameofdb-us-west-2b.abcdef123456.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -ujdoe -psecurepassword;
show databases;`

If goodnameofdb is not exist, you need create a db withe the name goodnameofdb.

`mysql> create DATABASE goodnameofdb;`

Then, try again.

Our team uses aurora also, aurora is compatible with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Aurora cluster, you mention a `database-name` name along with `master-user` and `master-user-password`. Here database refers to a default mysql database (also referred to `schema` at times) and NOT your db cluster identifier (in your example "goodnameofdb").

In your case, it looks like the default database that you created is either NOT NAMED `goodnameofdb` or you DIDN'T PROVIDE one explicitly, thereby making Aurora create some default database for you.

You cannot use AWS CLI to fetch the database name of your db instance. Use your master-user credentials, connect to the db via mysql cli (or something similar) and list the databases (`show databases;`) that are there in your Aurora cluster.

I'm fairly sure you are trying to use a non-existent mysql database.